# Convert all the strings in a list to date format

Tags: python, datetime, python-datetime

Need to convert strings present in "all_dates" to date format.
I am able to convert all of them to date format and print inside the loop. But unable to print them outside the loop. Can I get "AllDates" as a list of dates, not list of Strings

```
from datetime import datetime, date
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

all_dates = ['06/11/2020', '26/10/2018']
AllDates = []
for item in range(len(all_dates)):
    dateinAT = datetime.strptime(newdate[item], '%d/%m/%Y').date()
    print(dateinAT)
    AllDates.append(dateinAT)
print(AllDates)
```

**Output of the above code:**
2020-11-06
2018-10-26

[datetime.date(2020, 11, 6), datetime.date(2018, 10, 26)]

**Required Output:** [2020-11-06, 2018-10-26]

Comment: It is not clear if you want `AllDates` to be a list of strings or a list of `date` objects

Comment: I want it to be a list of date objects

Comment: So add it to your question, because all the answers you received assume otherwise.

Comment: Why was Selenium tagged?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Answering after OP clarified they want to keep `AllDates` a list of `date` objects. All the other answers have it as a list of strings*

First and foremost, it is important to understand that this is just a representation thing. When you print `dateinAT` inside the loop you get the output in the format that `datetime.date.__str__` returns it. However, when you print the `AllDates` list outside of the loop, you get each `date` object in the format that `datetime.date.__repr__` returns.

See [Difference between __str__ and __repr__?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436703/difference-between-str-and-repr) for more info on `__str__` and `__repr__`.

After clearing that, and if you still think it is worthwhile to get `[2020-11-06, 2018-10-26]` as the output of `print(AllDates)`, this can be achieved by using a class that subclasses `list` with a custom implementation of `__str__` (which will use each element's `__str__` method instead of `__repr__`).

```
from collections import UserList

class DatesList(UserList):
    def __str__(self):
        return '[' + ', '.join(str(e) for e in self) + ']'
        # as an exercise, change str(e) to repr(e) and see that you get the default output


all_dates = ['06/11/2020', '26/10/2018']
AllDates = DatesList() # <- note we use our new class instead of list() or []
for item in range(len(all_dates)):
    dateinAT = datetime.strptime(all_dates[item], '%d/%m/%Y').date()
    AllDates.append(dateinAT)

print(AllDates)
print([type(e) for e in AllDates])
```

This outputs

```
[2020-11-06, 2018-10-26]
[<class 'datetime.date'>, <class 'datetime.date'>]
```

**and** keeps `AllDates` a list of `date` objects.

Answer (score 0):

The `print()` calls the `__str__`method of the datetime.date object.
a quick but not so sophisticated way to solve your problem would be:

```
AllDates.append(dateinAT.__str__())
```

The better version would be using the `strftime` method

```
AllDates.append(dateinAT.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
```

Comment: Use `str(dateinAT)` instead of `dateinAT.__str__()`, though this might a wrong answer, since it will make `AllDates` a list of strings instead of a list of `date` objects

Answer (score 0):

You code store the values as `datetime` values. So you need to convert that to `str` using `strftime`.

So, Change this line to

```
dateinAT = datetime.strptime(newdate[item], '%d/%m/%Y').date()
```

this

```
dateinAT = datetime.strptime(newdate[item], '%d/%m/%Y').strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a list comprehension:

```py
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> all_dates = ['06/11/2020', '26/10/2018']
>>> AllDates = [
    datetime.strptime(item, '%d/%m/%Y').date().strftime('%Y-%m-%d') for item in all_dates]
['2020-11-06', '2018-10-26']
```